# Uso e significato di "come un turbine"

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Nel racconto *Nichel* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Sotto lo sguardo divertito e scettico di Alida, che, essendo ormai pomeriggio avanzato, guardava ostentatamente l’orologio da polso, mi misi al lavoro **come un turbine**. In un attimo, l’apparecchio fu montato, il termostato tarato a 800°C, il riduttore di pressione della bombola regolato, il flussimetro messo a posto.

Il testo lo posso più o meno capire, ma l'espressione "come un turbine" ha attirato la mia attenzione. Una ricerca su Google di questa locuzione dà parecchie occorrenze. La mia domanda è: si tratta di qualche sorta di paragone usuale per indicare il fare qualcosa a grande velocità?

Comment: ...come la rena quando turbo spira. (Non c'entra veramente, se non nella categoria più generale “similitudini in cui si menzionano turbini”.)

Comment: @DaG: «Finalmente nuovi casi, più generali, più forti, più estremi, arrivarono anche fino a loro, fino agli infimi di loro, secondo la scala del mondo: come un turbine vasto, incalzante, vagabondo, [...]».

Comment: @Charo, di chi è la citazione qui sopra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turbine significa: vortice  impetuoso del vento. Ad esempio *piante  sradicate dal turbine.*

Questo termine trova spesso applicazioni in senso figurato, ad esempio:

> (fig., scherz.) Movimento turbinoso: *gettarsi nel turbine della danza*.

> (estens.) Forza tumultuosa, che rapisce, sconvolge, travolge: *il turbine della vita, della guerra; essere preso nel turbine degli affari*

> (fig.) Moltitudine, quantità tumultuosa e travolgente: *un turbine di gente affamata; un turbine di zanzare; un turbine  di idee, di sentimenti contrastanti, di pensieri.*

***Come un turbine***,  significa con forza, con impeto e velocità.

(Fonte: [dizionario Hoepli](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/T/turbine.html))

[Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22come%20un%20turbine%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_it) “come un turbine”

Comment: Grazie, @Hachi. Se veramente "come un turbine" è un'espressione più o meno usuale per esprimere questa idea, potresti aggiungerlo alla risposta, per favore? Perché la domanda è più sull'uso dell'espressione (anche se grazie alla tua risposta il significato adesso mi è più chiaro).

Comment: Credo che a volte si usi anche per dare l'idea di velocità oltre che di forza.